# When starting a new react-native project do I have to change my Deployment Target to iOS 14 as per Apple?

Tags: ios, react-native-ios

On the Apple Developer Website https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/, it mentions that

> Starting April 26, 2021, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 12 and the iOS 14 SDK.

Does that mean that I have to change the deployment target in my React-Native project to iOS 14 to get it accepted by Apple when submitting it?

Comment: No, it means you need to build with the iOS 14 SDK and Xcode 12. You can set your minimum supported ios level lower. If you like.

Comment: Ah ok, I see that I was getting the iOS SDK confused with the deployment target by thinking they were the same thing and that by changing the deployment target, you change the SDK that you're using in Xcode 12. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS SDK and Deployment Target are two different things in XCode and lowering the deployment target in XCode 12 does not change the fact that you're using iOS 14.

All that changing the deployment target means is you're lowering the minimum supported iOS version for your app.